# Center text under a image/icon within a div

Tags: html, css

Trying to get some text to center under a image, but so far have been unable to do so. Tried looking up some other similar questions here but to no avail. The image and the text I am trying to center are within the same div, so both the image and the text uses the same text-align property. This div simply creates a css circle object around the image and text.

Already tried placing my text into a span, into the same element hoping the text would automatically go to the bottom if there was not enough room to fit the text into the css generated circle, etc...

```css
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  border: 4px double #000000;
  line-height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #181547
}

.menu img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  {{ content }}
  <div>
    <a href="" class="menu"><img src="/assets/img/About_icon.jpg"></a><span>About</span>
    <a href="" class="menu"><img src=""></a><span>Brands</span>
    <a href="" class="menu"><img src=""></a><span>DMS</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the end, I just want there to be a circle (already there) with an image and text inside which is centered with the text underneath the image, or even have the text outside of the circle and just underneath the circle instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.menu{
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#000000;
  border: 4px double #000000;
  line-height:250px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  background:#ffffff;
}

  .menu:hover{
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#181547
  }

  .menu img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .test{
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .text-center{
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
  {{ content }}
  <span  style="display: flex; width: fit-content;">
    <div class="test">
      <a href="" class="menu"><img src="/assets/img/About_icon.jpg"></a><div class="text-center">About</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="test"><a href="" class="menu">Insert Image</a><div class="text-center">Brands</div></div>
    <div class="test"><a href="" class="menu">Insert Image</a><div class="text-center">DMS</div></div>
    
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.menu{
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#000000;
  border: 4px double #000000;
  line-height:250px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  background:#ffffff;
}

  .menu:hover{
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#181547
  }

  .menu img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .test{
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .text-center{
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  {{ content }}
  <div  style="display: flex;">
    <div class="test">
      <a href="" class="menu"><img src="/assets/img/About_icon.jpg"></a><div class="text-center">About</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="test"><a href="" class="menu">Insert Image</a><div class="text-center">Brands</div></div>
    <div class="test"><a href="" class="menu">Insert Image</a><div class="text-center">DMS</div></div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
          {{ content }}
          <div  style="display: flex;">
            <div class="test">
              <a href="" class="menu"><img src="/assets/img/About_icon.jpg"></a><div class="text-center">About</div>
            </div>

            <div class="test"><a href="" class="menu">Insert Image</a><div class="text-center">Brands</div></div>
            <div class="test"><a href="" class="menu">Insert Image</a><div class="text-center">DMS</div></div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. Just noticed that the circles are now on the left hand-side of the page rather then centered. Anyway I can fix that?

Comment: Worked, thank you. Circles now in the center of page as expected, just now noticed the text below the circle seems to be a bit off center and a bit to the right.

Comment: Fixed it, all fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `img` and `span` under the same element and removing the `line-height` then you have to options.

### Using margin

You can give the `img` `display: block` and `margin: auto` styles and `text-align-center` for the parent that has both `img` and `span`

### Using flexbox

Giving the parent `display: flex` style and `justify-content: center`, `align-items: center` and 'flex-direction: column` will give you the result you want

---

### Check the snippet

```css
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  border: 4px double #000000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #181547
}

.menu img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;  
}


/* Edit */

/* ====== Without flex ====== */  
/*.wrapper div {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper img{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
*/

/* ====== With flex ====== */  
.menu{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  {{ content }}
  <div>
    <a href="" class="menu"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/150"><span>About</span></a>
    <a href="" class="menu"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/150"><span>Brands</span></a>
    <a href="" class="menu"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/150"><span>DMS</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a { 
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

One of those should center everything.

Also try using

```
.menu {
  Text-align:center;
}
```